# Compile Error: Invalid bind expression type of Schema.SObjectField for column of type Id at line 4 column 74

Tags: apex

```
public class Department2 {
public List<Employee__c> getDept()
{
    List<Employee__c> dept=[select Name from Employee__c WHERE DName__c=:Department__c.Id];
    return dept;
}

}
```

Comment: is DName__c is a field of type of Id? What is department__c ? i am assuming its a custom object and you need to declare a variable of sobjecttype department__c and assign value into it and use it in your bind expression

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange vin.  Usually questions are hard to understand or answer if there's so little detail and context provided. It's good that you've shared the code, but explaining what it's doing or what object and data you're trying to query will also help. Trying to explain a problem may even make you think about it in a way that shows you the issue without our help. You can still update the question by editting it.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `:Department__c.Id declared` ?

1. The `:` binding operator can be used to bind **Apex variables** into your SOQL if they are accessible to your apex context.
2. I suspect Department__c is a lookup field on your employee record. **Ifso:** Lookup fields are stored as the ID, so doing `Department__c.Id` wouldn't make sense. If you want to access other fields than the ID, and trancend the relationship you should use the relationship syntax `Department__r.fieldname__c`.
3. However: **in SOQL you can't compare on 2 fields in the table/sObject you're performing a query on**. One side of the values you want to compare needs to come from apex, this could be a single value or a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your query where you are using the phrase **"Department__c.Id"** - this refers to the Id field on the generic **Department__c** SObject class (and hence returns the Schema.SobjectField Type).

You need to use an instance of a particular Department__c. So if your **Department__c** was stored in a variable called **dep** it would read:

```
public List<Employee__c> getDept(){
     Department__c dep = new Department__c();
     //**Apply Logic to fetch dep depending on your business need and then query as below**//
     List<Employee__c> dept=[select Name from Employee__c WHERE DName__c=:dep.Id];
     return dept;
}
```

Cheers!